# How to write user inputs to an excel file?

Tags: python, excel

How can I put user inputs into an excel file? I'm planning to ask the students' name, year, and program to make a "database" or list in excel. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily write your data as .csv file using built-in csv module:

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html

MS Excel will open those files

This option is the best in my opinion, as it requires no additional modules

If you really need to write .xls/.xlsx files - take a look at OpenPyxel:

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/